# C# Stream.Read with timeout

Tags: c#, sockets, timeout, streamreader

I have this streamreader:

```
            Boolean read = false;
            while (wline!="exit")
            {

                while (!read || streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    read = true;
                    Console.Write((char)streamReader.Read());
                }
                wline = Console.ReadLine();
                streamWriter.Write(wline+"\r\n");
                streamWriter.Flush();

            }
```

How to set a timeout for Read() method?
thanks

Comment: Is this with a TCPClient?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If this is `System.IO.StreamReader`, then set it on the `BaseStream`:

```
streamReader.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = 2000;  //milliseconds, so 2 seconds
```

Comment: do you have any idea what is default timeout value ?

Comment: @SHAHS No.  It's not obvious to me looking at the source where that value comes from.  Best I can suggest is put a breakpoint on it and look.

Comment: When applied to a /dev/ttysomething on linux, it raises an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.

Answer (score 13):

You need to deal with the underlying stream. So, in case you are using a TcpClient, you can simply set the ReceiveTimeout:

> The [ReceiveTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout.aspx) property determines the amount of time that the
>   Read method will block until it is able to receive data. This time is
>   measured in milliseconds. If the time-out expires before Read
>   successfully completes, TcpClient throws a IOException. There is no
>   time-out by default.

```
 tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
```